# Complex minimization to minimize $\cos \alpha$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Let $\alpha,\beta,$ and $\gamma$ be three real numbers. Suppose that
$$\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma=1$$
$$\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma=1.$$
Find the smallest possible value of $\cos \alpha.$ (Source: [HMMT 2018 Algebra and Number Theory](https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2018/feb/algnt/problems.pdf) #6)

---

I assumed that $\beta = \gamma$ was optimal and got the right answer. However, I was unable to prove afterwards that this was optimal, so I referred to the [Official Solutions](https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2018/feb/algnt/solutions.pdf) (Scroll to #6). They let $a = \cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha$, and so on, and state that $a,b,c$ must be on the unit circle, which I understand. I also understand that we want to minimize the real part of $a$.

However, they then consider a triangle with vertices $a, 1+i$ the origin, and state that $a$ must be as far away from $1+i$ while maintaining a nonnegative imaginary part. They state that this implies the argument of $b$ and $c$ are the same. I don't understand the aforementioned in this paragraph, could someone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the argumentation slightly differently.

$$a+b+c=1+i \quad \Rightarrow \quad |1+i-a|=|b+c|. $$
Now,
$$\begin{aligned}|b+c|^2 &=|(\cos \beta + \cos \gamma)^2+(\sin\beta + \sin \gamma)^2|\\\\&=|2+2(\cos\beta \cos\gamma + \sin\beta\sin\gamma)|\\\\&=|2+2\cos(\beta-\gamma)|\\\\&\leq4,\end{aligned}$$
which is attained when $\beta=\gamma.$
Thus, the maximal distance between the points given by $\;a\;$ and $\;1+i\;$ is $\;2.$ Now, we can consider a $1-2-\sqrt2$ triangle with vertices at $a,1+i,0.$ There are two convenient points $a,a'$ on unit circle. Only one of them has negative real part.